# Is it possible to do a case-insensitive `gsub`?

Tags: ruby, regex, case-insensitive

I am doing a `gsub` to swap `"bad"` for `"good"`. Is there a way to use `capitalize` so it will swap both lower and upper case? Or will I have to write the `def` twice?

```
def add_more_ruby(string)
  string.gsub('bad','good').capitalize
end
```

Comment: If you are not sure of a behavior of a method, it is better not to make a wild guess in describing it. Here, your mentioning of `capitalize` is irrelevant to what you actually wanted to do, and it is making your question very hard to understand. Instead, write what you want to do in ordinary words.

Comment: Do you expect `Bad` to be replaced with `Good` or with `good`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can pass [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) instead of `String`, with `i` option that indicates that this regexp is case insensitive:

```
def add_more_ruby(string)
  string.gsub(/bad/i, 'good')
end
```

note that it will substitute not only `'bad'` and `'BAD'`, but also, for example, `'bAd'`. If you want to substitute only all-uppercase or all-lowercase, you can do:

```
string.gsub(/bad|BAD/, 'good')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to use the block form of `gsub` to handle different capitalisations differently:

```
string.gsub(/bad/i) do |match|
  match == 'Bad' ? 'Good' : 'good'
end
```

When the regexp matches, the block is executed, and the return value of the block is used as the replacement.

So this will replace 'Bad' with 'Good', and 'bad' written with any other permutation of capital and lower-case letters (including 'bad' but also 'BAD', 'bAD' etc) with 'good'.